# Configure python3 pointing to /usr/bin/python3.8 in Linux Mint after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

I have installed Anaconda 1.9.12 on my Linux Mint 20 machine, which had python3.8 installed by default. However, after the installation both `python` and `python3` point towards the `python` interpreter in the Anaconda installation.

```
$ which python
~/anaconda3/bin/python

$ which python3
~/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

As I wanted `python3` to point towards `python3.8`, I have tried `update-alternatives` to create a symlink pointing `python3` to `\usr\bin\python3.8` by issuing the following in the terminal.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 15
```

I want to use the Python interpreter provided by Anaconda and the default one simultaneously. However, I cannot realise this. I  What might have gone wrong?

**Update 1**: I have uncommented the changes made in `~/.bashrc` by Anaconda. Even though that would let me use the Python provided by the distribution, I won't be able to launch the `anaconda-navigator`.

***PS**: This is not a duplicate question. I have referred to almost all the similar questions. Most of them are unrelated issues, the rest of them did not work out, like the one I mentioned above.*

Comment: Perhaps Anaconda added an aliasing to your `~/.bashrc` file that points to the new installation.

Comment: @James: I have commented out the initialization script inserted by Anaconda in '~/.bashrc'. It has solved my earlier issue, however, I cannot open 'anaconda-navigator' or 'jupyter-lab'.

Comment: You might have to call `conda activate base` to shift into the Anaconda environment before starting the navigator.

Comment: @James: I get an error, 'bash: conda: command not found' when I issue that command.

Comment: If you installed Conda, why not just stick to using that? _However, I cannot realise the change I want._ What does that mean, specifically?

Comment: @AMC: I must be able to use the python interpreters from Anaconda, and the one in the system simultaneously. It is a matter of convenience. Also, I was able to use it that way previously.=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a *similar* issue in Debian with an installation of multiple CPython (2.7, 3.8, and 3.9; apparently all from the distribution's repositories). So far, aiming to set the preference to version 3.9,  the approach outlined by author «John» on [skillsugar.com](https://www.skillsugar.com/how-to-change-the-default-python-version) works well enough for me:

- Determine the Python interpreter currently installed.  The simple `which python` / `which python3` offers a potentally incomplete description of the the initial state.  As recommended by the original source -- assuming installation in the default paths --  run `ls /usr/bin/python2*` and `ls /usr/bin/python3*`  instead.
- One after the other, I run

  `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 1`

  `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2`

  `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 3`

  Here, the trailing `1`, `2`, and `3` only serve as priority numbers for the subsequent step.
- The third step was to call `sudo update-alternatives --config python`.  In my case, the CLI's output displayed the following table:

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python2.7   3         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   3         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.9   1         manual mode
```

From this menu, I selected option `3` and confirmed by `Enter`.  As intended, `python` now refers to Python 3.9.2 while retaining access to Python 2.7.18 with a (then explicit) call of `python2` (which remains listed in status «auto mode»).  It may be that this change demands subsequent adjustments in your workflow (e.g., use of `pytest-3` instead of `pytest`).